# Datagridview Row Post Paint infinite loop issue

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am programming in VB.NET inside windows forms with an sql back end. My issue is I am using two separate SQL queries to try and color multiple datagridview rows yellow, red, or green. The problem is that for each row, I check the row to see if it should be yellow, and then I check the same row to see if it should be green. I set all rows to red to begin with. I think the problem is that if a row is originally set to red, when I change it to yellow, it restarts the the row post paint event.

```
   Private Sub DataGridView1_RowPostPaint(sender As Object, e As 
DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.RowPostPaint

Datagridview1.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red

        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE OrderNO = @Order AND LEFT(Item, 10) = @Part AND [Cut?] = 1", conn1)
                With comm1.Parameters
                    .AddWithValue("@Order", Datagridview1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("OrderNO").Value)
                    .AddWithValue("@Part", Datagridview1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Part").Value)
                End With
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim sql As New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
                sql.Fill(dt)
                If dt.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
                    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                End If
            End Using
            conn1.Close()
        End Using

        Using conn1 As New SqlConnection(connstring)
            conn1.Open()
            Using comm1 As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE OrderNo = @Order AND LEFT(ItemNum, 10) = @Part AND [Completed?] = 1", conn1)
                With comm1.Parameters
                    .AddWithValue("@Order", DataGridView1(e.RowIndex).Cells("Order").Value)
                    .AddWithValue("@Part", DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("Part").Value)
                End With
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim sql As New SqlDataAdapter(comm1)
                sql.Fill(dt)
                If dt.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
                    DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green
                End If
            End Using
            conn1.Close()
        End Using
  End Sub
```

The datagridview does load and it does color in all the rows but the program is obviously doing something because cells will blink as if the program is doing something to the rows. The form also freezes up, not as in it crashed, but as in the form is unresponsive because its too busy running the row post paint code. I need to find a way for this code to run once on each line and then stop.

Comment: Well, the *post* paint event runs *after* a row has been painted, so your code is sometimes changing the row color causing the row to paint again.

Comment: Wow, that's a lot of processing on the UI thread.

Comment: @Plutonix Is there a different event I should try or a way to hit each row once?

Comment: These could almost certainly be combined into a single SQL query.

Comment: At the very least your could have a datatabe of that query and simply query or filter the table so that you are not poking the DB 2ce per row.  That is, if you cant tuck those columns away in the DGV and just evaluate them.  If the task is to color rows conditionally, do it in the *pre* paint event

Comment: @Plutonix It could be put into a single query and I have tried that but even if I do that I still have to paint the row. This causes the event to run again. The single query was an sql query that called both the "cut" and "completed" columns which were both check boxes. After that I set two variables into chk1 and chk2 to see what color to paint. Then I used an if/then statement to try and logic the paint. This still caused the same error.

Comment: @Cheddar you can start by putting this into `DataGridView1_CellValueChanged` instead. This should stop your infinite loop (because you aren't changing values, only colors). But I would still run the query only once, as long as the sql data isn't changing between dgv edits, and simply query a local copy of the data you could store in a private field in your class.

Comment: @djv Will do, I'll get back to you

Comment: @djv I attempted putting this into the cellValueChanged and it did not execute the code. The datagridview is being populated on a cell double click of another datagridview. Could this be why it is not executing the cell value change event. The datagridview is read only.

Comment: Then call it after you double click the other dgv... You can pass the row index from it i'd imagine.

Comment: @Cheddar there's many ways you can do it but you have to stay out the paint event. You could have a timer that triggers it.